# Retrieving auth0id using auth0-react-native-sample

Tags: react-native, auth0

I'm currently trying out Auth0 and messing around with a sample app:
https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-native-sample

I am trying to get hold of the user I am logging in as and getting the authId but what I'm getting in return is the client details:

```
const onLogin = () => {
    auth0.webAuth
        .authorize({
            scope: 'openid profile email'
        })
        .then(credentials => {
            const user = auth0.users(credentials.accessToken);
            console.log(user);
            Alert.alert('AccessToken: ' + credentials.accessToken);
            setAccessToken(credentials.accessToken);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

Result:

```
{
    "client": {
        "telemetry": {
            "name": "react-native-auth0",
            "version": "2.14.1"
        },
        "baseUrl": "<BASE URL>",
        "domain": "<DOMAIN>",
        "bearer": "Bearer <TOKEN>",
        "timeout": 10000
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get a hold of the authId via this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to access it via this way:

```
auth0.auth.userInfo({token: credentials.accessToken}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```